# Google Apps Script set value to multiple cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have google spreadsheet and a function for it to calculate some values basing on first 3 cells in a row.

My problem is that this function returns multiple values which shold be placed in multiple cells in current row.

```
function test(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
  return [arg1 + 1, arg2 + 1, arg3 + 1];
}
```

For example.
How i tell it to put values from array to different cells?

Comment: Read `setValues()` documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the question is about a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions), the following function will return a 1 row x 3 columns array

```
function test(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
  return [[arg1 + 1, arg2 + 1, arg3 + 1]];
}
```